# Counting the sum $\sum^{\infty}_{k=0} q^{k^{2}}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Is it possible to obtain explicit form of the sum
$\sum^{\infty}_{k=0} q^{k^{2}}$ (without using elliptic functions)?

It is well known that $\sum^{\infty}_{k=0} q^{k} = \frac{1}{1-q}$ for all $q \in (-1; 1)$ but counting the sum $\sum^{\infty}_{k=0} q^{k^{2}}$ seems almost impossible to me.

Thank you for all useful ideas!

Comment: It's a theta-function. It can't be expressed in finite terms, in terms of the functions familiar from high school and 1st year undergrad math.

Comment: Thank you. Do you have any explanation for it?

Comment: What would count as an explanation for something not having an expression in finite terms? There are proofs, but they use pretty advanced stuff. Start by seeing what the web says about theta functions.